# Unfortunately Application has stopped in android

Tags: android, sockets

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

     private Socket client;
     private PrintWriter printwriter;
     private EditText etMsg, etIP, etPort;
     private Button button;
     private String messsage;
     int port=0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        etIP=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        etPort=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        etMsg=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                messsage=etMsg.getText().toString();
                etMsg.setText("");
                port=Integer.parseInt(etPort.getText().toString());

                try
                {
                    client=new Socket(etIP.getText().toString(), port);
                    printwriter= new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(),true);
                    printwriter.write(messsage);
                    printwriter.flush();
                    printwriter.close();
                    client.close();
                }

                catch(UnknownHostException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



            }
        });
    }


}
```

Above is my code for socket programming. I have developed it in 2.2 froyo. It works fine on Android device and gives me proper output. But when I develope and run this code on latest version of Android such as IceCreamSandwhich and Jellybean, it shows me an error like Unfortunately Application has stopped. What is the problem, I am not getting it. Please help me to solve this. Manifest file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.empty"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>


    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="14" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.empty.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: show the `logcat` output...

Comment: i think [NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html)  ?

Comment: Move your network related task in different thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move your network related task in different thread like this

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Socket client;
    private PrintWriter printwriter;
    private EditText etMsg, etIP, etPort;
    private Button button;
    private String messsage;
    int port = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        etIP = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        etPort = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        etMsg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                messsage = etMsg.getText().toString();
                etMsg.setText("");
                port = Integer.parseInt(etPort.getText().toString());

                new Thread(new Runnable() 
                {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        try 
                        {
                            client = new Socket(etIP.getText().toString(), port);
                            printwriter = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(),true);
                            printwriter.write(messsage);
                            printwriter.flush();
                            printwriter.close();
                            client.close();
                        }

                        catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }       
                    }
                }).start();


            }
        });
    }

}
```

Let me know if you face any problem with this.

Comment: @Juned..where should I put this run method? Means on button click?

Comment: @Juned..Let me try it.And Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Juned...My app is installed successfully and also does not prompt any Unfortunately stopped message but it does not give me any output.

Comment: @AnilBhatiya your actual problem is solved, does your code working properly on low sdk vesrsions ?

Comment: @Juned..My original code is working fine on lower versions. I developed it on 2.2 froyo.

Comment: ohh sorry, i just forget to start that thread, just start the thread and it will work fine, i have updated the code

Comment: @Juned...My question is how can I send whole .txt file and .doc file to the server. In my GUI I have to provide path of user choice. Means user has to choose the path of file that he/she wants to send...Please help me to solve my problem...Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

you can this code for your mainActivity.java file

```
sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }
    }
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```